# I have 3 tables and having a relationship, which is the best way to retrieve the data

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I am using Java and JPA, i know below 2 ways but which is the best way performance wise.
One is simple we can get one by one table data and return it to user.
Another way i will use JOIN and write a select query to get the data.

But i wanted to know any other way or which is better.

Comment: Fewer round trips to the database server almost always leads to being faster.

Answer (score 0):

Any decent rdbms has a powerful optimizer, that will analyze the JOIN and other query elements, to find the most efficient way to get the data, taking into account the size of the different tables, indexes, cache strategies, etc.  You will never outperform an optimizer by reading records one by one.

Moreover, as soon as some selections intervene, there are big chances that the JOIN will need your application to access to less data than reading each table. This may have significant performance impact if the db is on a distinct server, and if your app is under high load.